# How to register a lamba per REST verb using AWS amplify

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have an amplify REST API (AWS Gateway + lambdas) and by default it's configured so all REST verbs go through the same lambda but I would like a lambda per verb.

Current setup

```
- Endpoint: /users/profile  
  Lambda: allProfileOperations.js
  HttpMethod: any
```

Desired setup

```
- Endpoint: /users/profile  
  HttpMethod: POST
  Lambda: createProfileOperation.js
- Endpoint: /users/profile  
  HttpMethod: PATCH
  Lambda: updateProfileOperation.js
```

[This article](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1232) mentions modifying the cloudformation file  however that was 2 years ago.

But if that is the only way to do this and you know what edits are required to the cloudformation file please let me know.

Comment: Somebody created an example [here](https://github.com/matsev/cloudformation-api-gateway/blob/master/cloudformation.template). Or you can consult the CloudFormation documentation... I can understand if you avoid it though, I ditched CloudFormation simply because reading its documentation is too time consuming.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Though having had some more time to think I'm leaning towards procisioning my backend with terraform and only using amplify for user auth (for now)